# Is AES-NI fully supported?

Tags: security, intel, luks

Has support for the Intel AES-NI hardware crypto acceleration been added to Ubuntu (LUKS, kernel, OpenSSL libs, etc)? If so, starting with which version?

Here is a list of Intel processors supporting AES-NI:

- http://ark.intel.com/MySearch.aspx?AESTech=true

More about AES-NI:

- http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-advanced-encryption-standard-instructions-aes-ni/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set#Software_supporting_AES_instruction_set
- http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/clarkdale-aes-ni-encryption,2538.html

I am mostly interested in finding out if this effectively suppresses / diminishes any performance penalties of using full disk encryption in Ubuntu.

Comment: Is this still valid with Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 5):

It is supported at least since Karmic Koala on the `amd64` architecture and since Natty Narwhal it is supported also on the `i386` architecture.

You can find that out by looking at the kernel configuration files found [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/configs/). Search for the term `CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES_NI_INTEL`.

Answer (score 4):

If your root partition is LUKS-encrypted you should add `aesni-intel` to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` (and run `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` afterwards).

Otherwise the module will be loaded too late in the boot process.

Comment: Is it necessary to blacklist the default `aes` module ?

Comment: I don't think that blacklisting is needed, at least not on Oneiric. By default AES is compiled into the kernel on Oneiric (CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES=y), only the NI-extensions are available as modules (CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES_X86_64=m and CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES_NI_INTEL=m).

Comment: You'll want to run `sudo update-initramfs -u` to update all of your existing kernels.

Comment: `sudo update-initramfs -u` will update your most recent/current kernel.  To update this for all, use `sudo update-initramfs -uk all`.

Answer (score 2):

Block level kernel encryption (dm-crypt) already full supports AES-NI cryptographic acceleration.

File level kernel encryption ([eCryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org)) support for AES-NI was [recently](https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/5/10/22) merged into the Linux upstream kernel tree, and should make its way into the Ubuntu kernel soon.  Perhaps 13.10?